# REACTJS Frontend is not populating the List Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I am currently working with a REACT JS frontend framework. I have this functionality where in the backend there is a folder with files. I would like to be able to edit that list of files and remove a certain amount based on what is selected in the drop down. I will send all of the code for the entire webpage. The functions im talking abount is:

`const renderEditTestPoolContainer` and `const renderEditContainer`

### The Main Focus Points

The main focus points are including the functions:

```
    const renderEditContainer = () => {
      if (showEditContainer) {
        return (
          <div className="edit-current-test-pool-container">
            <h1 className="edit-current-test-pool-header">Edit Current Test Pool</h1>
            <div className="current-list-container">
              <h3 className="current-list-title">Current List</h3>
              <ul>
                {fileNames.map((fileName, index) => (
                  <li key={index}>{fileName}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <button className="edit-button" onClick={handleEditButtonClick}>
              Edit
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
      return null;
    };
```

and the

```
    const renderEditTestPoolContainer = () => {
      if (showEditTestPoolContainer) {
        return (
          <div className="edit-test-pool-container">
            <div className="edit-test-pool-content">
              <div className="edit-test-pool-form">
                <form onSubmit={handleRemoveButtonClick}>
                  <h1 className="edit-test-pool-header">Edit the Test Pool</h1>
                  <div className="amount-input-container">
                    <label htmlFor="test-dropdown" className="amount-input">
                      Items to remove:
                    </label>
                    {selectedTests.map((selectedTest, index) => (
                      <select
                        key={index}
                        className="form-select"
                        onChange={(event) => handleTestSelection(event, index)}
                        value={selectedTest}
                      >
                        <option key={`empty-${index}`} value="">
                          -- Select a test --
                        </option>
                        {tests.length > 0 &&
                          tests.map((test) => (
                            <option key={test.id} value={test.id}>
                              {test.name}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                      </select>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                  <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="num-of-tests" className="form-label">
                      Number of Tests in Sequence:
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      id="num-of-tests"
                      name="num-of-tests"
                      className="form-control"
                      value={numOfTests}
                      onChange={handleUpdateNumOfTests}
                    />
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-primary"
                      onClick={handleUpdateTests}
                    >
                      Update
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <button className="remove-button" onClick={handleRemoveButtonClick}>
                    Remove
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
      return null;
    };
```

Here is a screenshot showing the failure to show items and also a video. While also including the console error message.

[image]

And here is an error code that i see:
[image]

This error is directly related to the list not populating. Yet i have a unique key being generated:

```
                    {selectedTests.map((selectedTest, index) => (
                      <select
                        key={index}
                        className="form-select"
                        onChange={(event) => handleTestSelection(event, index)}
                        value={selectedTest}
                      >
                        <option key={`empty-${index}`} value="">
                          -- Select a test --
                        </option>
                        {tests.length > 0 &&
                          tests.map((test) => (
                            <option key={test.id} value={test.id}>
                              {test.name}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                      </select>
                    ))}
```

## Question Amendments

*Description*: Area for amendments asked in comments.

### Amendment 1: Can you show the code where the tests are being pulled or populated:

```
  const handleEditClick = () => {
    // Logic for handling "Edit" click
    setShowEditContainer(true);
    setAccountScreen(false);
    setShowTakeTest(false);
    setShowNewContainer(false);
    fetchFileList();
  }

  const handleEditButtonClick = () => {
    setShowEditTestPoolContainer(true);
  }

  const handleUpdateTests = () => {
    if (isNaN(numOfTests) || numOfTests === '') {
      setErrorMessage('Invalid Value Entered, please enter only numeric values');
      return;
    }

    const updatedSelectedTests = Array(numOfTests).fill('');
    setSelectedTests(updatedSelectedTests);
    setErrorMessage('');
  };

  const handleTestSelection = (event, index) => {
    const updatedSelectedTests = [...selectedTests];
    updatedSelectedTests[index] = event.target.value;
    setSelectedTests(updatedSelectedTests);
  };
  
  const handleUpdateNumOfTests = (event) => {
    const value = parseInt(event.target.value);
    setNumOfTests(value);
  };

  const handleRemoveButtonClick = () => {
    const filesToRemove = Object.values(selectedTests).filter((fileName) => !!fileName);
    // Perform logic to remove the selected files
  
    // Example implementation:
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/remove-files', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ files: filesToRemove }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Files removed successfully');
        // Perform any necessary actions, such as updating the file list or displaying a success message
        fetchFileList(); // Fetch the updated file list from the server
        setShowEditTestPoolContainer(false); // Hide the edit container
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        // Handle any errors that occurred during the request
        // Display an error message or perform appropriate error handling
      });
  };
```

As for the fetchFileList:

```
const fetchFileList = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/get-file-names')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTests(data);
        console.log(tests);
        setFileNames(data);
        console.log(fileNames);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        // Handle any errors that occurred during the request
      });
  };
```

### Amendment 2: The following image shows that the same fetchFileList function is working for this menu right before the selection and remove screen

[image]

## Youtube Link for error

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hY7xAQ26Rj8

Comment: Can you show the code where you are populating or setting the 'tests' that is getting used inside 'renderEditTestPoolContainer '?

Comment: @Junaid Thankyou so much for commenting, i just updated the post to show those pieces of code

Comment: Thanks for updating. Can you verify you are actually calling the 'fetchFileList ' function? And how are you doing this?

Comment: Sidenote" *"And here is an error code that i see: Warning: Each child ..."* - That's not an error, that's a warning. You shouldn't ignore it, but it also _shouldn't_ break your code... Also, you don't have unique keys; `key={index}` and `key={test.id}` could very easily conflict. If `index` is `1`, and `test.id` is also `1`, then you have a non-unique key. Use a prefix: `key={\`select_${index}\`}` and `key={\`option_${test.id}\`}` (or similar)

Comment: You've put a lot of effort into trying to make this reproducible, without making it reproducible. There are two possible scenarios: a) (most probable) the response from your API does not match what the app expects. In this case, you should look at what you're doing in the backend and how that response is generated; b) the fault is somewhere in the React app. If it's b) and you need help, I suggest creating a *runnable* [mcve] (using codesandbox.io or similar) where you replace the API request with a simple `() => Promise.resolve(someData)`.

Comment: @Junaid the fetchFileList is connecting to a backend that has a folder that contains all of the files, it created an arrayList for the names of the files and assigns an id. So here i want that array to be manipulated by this remove functionality. However, the dropdown menus are not showing any of the files./ I also already have this similar functionality working on another webpage. So its confusing why its not working here. It is correctly pulling the information ill attach a screenshot of the fetchFileList correctly pulling the names of the files in a list order

Comment: @tao The backend in this case i just pulling the file names in this call. It is working, however it isnt displaying the text but a similar amount of options and when you click on options nothing gets selected.

Comment: @巨人の殺人者 I would highly recommend following the tao comment. This way you can get instant help. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if `tests.length > 0 && tests.map((test)` is an issue? I'm not sure if you can use `&& tests.map()` like that. Typical syntax I would use is `{tests.length ? tests.map(...) : undefined}`, or even simply `tests.map(...)` since `.map()` on an empty array does nothing anyway.

Comment: @TimLewis whats strange is that it works on another webpage with the same logic

Comment: Hmm ok, so it would be valid syntax, albeit a little redundant due to how `.map()` works. Have you added any debugging statements or added any breakpoints? I.e. `console.log(tests.length)`; if that is `0`, then that would explain why your `<option>`s are not rendering, and would point you towards there being an issue setting `tests` to a non-empty array, etc.

Comment: Is it the same logic or the same exact code? If it's same exact code, compare the server responses between the two. (It can't be the app). If it's not the the same exact code, compare the server responses + the parts of the app you've changed.

Comment: TimLewis, @tao, and Junaid 

Thankyou so much for helping me, i just posted the solution in the post. I had found that i needed to do the same Get request... duh thank you for letting me realize this! Thanks alot again, everyone!

Comment: Answers should be posted as an answer *(you can accept your own answer)* rather than putting answers in the question. Tangentially I might reconsider the volume and formatting of the words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to dig deeper into the functionality on the other webpage with the same functionality as here where I had this issue. I had to use a different fetch method to fix the issue. Below is the code I had changed. Thankyou again everyone who helped especially: @tao @TimLewis and @Junaid

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
const handleEditButtonClick = () => {
    setShowEditTestPoolContainer(true);
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/test/questions')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const testsFromServer = data.map((test) => ({
        id: test,
        name: test,
      }));
      setTests(testsFromServer);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));
  }
```